# Root account expired

Tags: linux, ubuntu, authentication, root

I had a colleague (he left the company) that did a "hardening" on Ubuntu servers. He put the following:

useradd -D -f 30 
chage --inactive 30 root

Which I understand that in 30 days the root account will expire... Now I couldn't log to root account.. because it is expired. I get a meesage saying:

```
Your account has expired; please contact your system administrator
```

Using my cloud provider portal I was able to create a new user (sudo user) and was able to change to root. But when I cange to root and put the password i'm still getting this:

```
Your account has expired; please contact your system administrator

su: Authentication failure

(Ignored)
```

Also I cannot change a password of ordinary user. I change it, then I log in and I get an authentication failure... crazy! maybe it is related to root issue..

I know that to re-enable an account I need to do it with root, but what about when the account you want to re-enable is root? :)

So, any idea about how can I fix this is welcome.

Thank you very much

Comment: You should be able to do this in recovery mode. I don't remember being asked for the root password to bring up the command line.

Comment: If you were "able to create a new user (sudo user) and [...] to change to root", why can't you use root to enable it?

Comment: Problem is that when I try to re-enable root with root user looks does not work... 

root@server1:~# passwd -u root
sent invalidate(passwd) request, exiting
sent invalidate(group) request, exiting
sent invalidate(passwd) request, exiting
sent invalidate(group) request, exiting
passwd: password expiry information changed

Comment: And when I try to login as user, "su root" I put the correct password and I just get a su: permission denied"

Comment: also, I get this:

Password has been already used.  even if the password is completely ramdom...

Comment: Issue solved, I reset the account using “/sbin/pam_tally2 -u my_user –reset”